# How can I start a different X session on tty8?

Tags: command-line, xorg, tty

Let's say, for an example, I want to run a full-screen opengl application on tty8 and have my standard GNOME desktop on tty7. How can I configure Ubuntu to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start a new X session on tty8, drop to tty1 (or 2-6) and type

```
startx -- :1
```

Comment: This works but sound and keyboard is still connected to the old one. When I switch to the other terminal, I am not able to use keyboard and sound doesn't appear. But mouse works though

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

> So, in the file :
>   /etc/X11/gdm/gdm.conf
>
> please mention that u'll like it in both :0 and :1
>   That should be indicated as follows :
>
> ```
>    ...
>    [servers]
>    # These are the standard servers. You can add as many you want here
>    # and they will always be started. Each line must start with a unique
>    # number and that will be the display number of that server. Usually just
>    # the 0 server is used.
>    0=Standard
>    1=Standard
>    # Note the VTAllocation and FirstVT keys on linux and freebsd.
>    # Don't add any vt<number> arguments if VTAllocation is on, and set FirstVT to
>    # be the first vt available that your gettys don't grab (gettys are usually
>    # dumb and grab even a vt that has already been taken). Using 7 will work
>    # pretty much for all linux distributions. VTAllocation is not currently
>    # implemented on anything but linux and freebsd. Feel free to send patches.
>    # X servers will just not get any extra arguments then.
>    #
>    ...
> ```

Extracted from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=86451. This is from 2005 but it should work.

Comment: This config file: */etc/X11/gdm/gdm.conf* is not in the location stated in the answer.