# How to keep a remote X11 app running after disconnecting SSH?

Tags: ssh, xorg, process, remote

I've got X11 forwarding on so I can see program windows on my server from my desktop, I'm wondering if I disconnect from the ssh session with the x11 forwarding to my PC, will that program close on the server side upon disconnecting? If it does, is there a way to prevent that?

I have MEGASync running on my server and it needs an X server running to use it, I cannot use VNC because iptables is acting strangely, can't open the port properly. I'd like to keep megasync running on the server without having to stay connected to SSH so I can turn my PC off.

Any way to do this?

Comment: I would use `screen` but not sure how that works with `-X`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Xpra](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xpra) seems to be exactly what you are looking for.
It's a bit like screen or tmux but for X11 applications.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10598/166985) on http://unix.stackexchange.com for an example.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 avenues I would explore. the simplest is just to keep the 
ssh alive by adding `ServerAliveInterval 60` to your ssh client config

```
cat <<- EOF >> $HOME/.ssh/config

    # send packets over ssh every 60 seconds to keep ssh connection alive
    ServerAliveInterval 60
EOF
```

or alternatively install screen or tmux, personally I use tmux

so on the server you would need to run

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

then launch tmux on server

```
tmux -2
```

connect to the server with

```
ssh -X -C -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour [-pPORT_NUM] user@1.2.3.4
```

where

- `-X` Enables X11 forwarding.
- `-C` Requests compression of all data (including stdin, stdout,
       stderr, and data for forwarded X11, TCP and UNIX-domain connec‐
       tions).
- `-c` is the cipher type

the compression stuff is not essentially but reduces lagginess/responsiveness with the server

Then launch your program from inside the tmux session

i.e.

```
$ your program
```

if your ssh gets disconnected, the program should remain running on the server, to reconnect with the program once you get a new ssh connection going, run

```
tmux attach
```

on the server

Comment: `-c blowfish-cbc,arcfour` Don't recommend using broken ciphers! Also compression is useless these days.